# What's the Difference?

Tags: computer-puzzle

*not sure if this counts as a real puzzle, but I will ask it anyways.

---

Can you catch the difference between the 2 following letters?

1. `х`
2. `x`

**Honor system: No using online tools to find the difference!**

(Deleting cause I’m getting downvoted)

Comment: Remember that there's a tag [tag:no-computers], for puzzles that should be solved without the use of online tools or computer programming.

Comment: @Hugh thank you. I left it out because it would somewhat contradict the “computer_puzzle” tag.

Comment: Oh, yeah... I guess you could have a computer puzzle that meant to be solved without computers; like a piece of computer code that errors and you have to figure out which line the error is on without a computer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well,

> the second is an ordinary lower case letter 'x', while the first is at Unicode code point 1093 decimal = 0x445. The surrounding Unicode code points yield what look to me like Cyrillic characters, so I guess that's what this one is; I think this letter is pronounced like a Scottish "ch", and is related e.g. to the Greek letter chi.

No online tools used; I

> pasted the characters into a Python session and used its `chr` and `ord` functions.

Comment: True... uhh. Not cheating, right? Umm... repost? Clarification! True, you weren’t cheating, but still. I was assuming the honor system **covered the rest**.

Comment: @qq410219243 Well, how do you *expect* people to figure it out then? In the font used here, those two characters look exactly the same - and if you're not allowed to distinguish them using any tools, then there's literally no way to tell them apart.

Comment: I agree with @Deusovi. I mean, you can do the same using tools built into the web browser, but I don't see any reason to regard that as more or less cheaty than doing it with Python. If all we're allowed to do is look with our eyes, then the answer is: No, we can't tell the difference.

Comment: Fair enough. Good job, you two!

Answer (score 4):

Easy way (though not sure if "allowed"):

> Paste into start menu. First x will show no results (or Greek stuff if you have it). Second x will show normal results matching x